# Change default compress option in Nautilus type to zip?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, compression, file-roller

On the right click menu (in Nautilus, desktop, etc), there is a "compress" option.  Is there any way to make "zip" the default format for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some investigating, it appears that this is controlled by a gconf setting. To set zip as the default compression method, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to launch the 'Run Application' window. Type 'gconf-editor' in the box and hit the 'Run' button. This can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Run Application Window]

Once you hit the 'Run' button, a window like the one below will appear. This is the Configuration Editor.

[image: Configuration Editor]

The compression feature of nautilus really uses `file-roller`. To get to the file-roller settings, start by expanding the 'apps' folder.

[image: Apps Folder]

Next, find and expand the 'file-roller' folder.

[image: file-roller folder]

Expand the 'dialogs' folder.

[image: dialogs folder]

Select the 'batch-add' folder.

[image: batch-add folder]

You should now see an item with the name of 'default_extension' in the section on the right. You will want to click on the 'Value' field and change whatever was previously there to '.zip'.

[image: default_extension = .zip]

Now, if you close the configuration editor and open nautilus, .zip should be the default compression method.

[image: .zip is default compression method in nautilus]

Comment: fantastic answer, thank you.  I shall try this out as soon as I get back to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you click on «compress» it will show you a window to select the format. The file format is the last chosen format.

Comment: I'm looking to make .zip the default in the dropdown if possible

Comment: It's rare, ZIP is installed by default. I know RAR is not installed in a fresh installation, but ZIP is. Try to search for «zip» in Software Center.

Comment: ZIP is available to select, but it is not the default.  The default is .tar.gz.  I'd like .zip to be the default, to help a user to ensure they are creating a compatible archive.

Comment: Well, in *NIX is very used .tar.gz, I see normal to set it as the default. To sum up, .tar.gz is free, .zip is not free in all cases -though the package used in GNU/Linux (Ubuntu in this case) is free-.

Comment: Is there any way I can change the default for this one computer?  The user has to submit coursework in .zip archives due to university rules.

Comment: I don't know why it must be the default format. If you compress a file and select ZIP it will be the selected one every time you compress any other file. If they wanna be sure they are selecting ZIP as compressing format they can select it and then check the file name, it will be «file.zip». The "default" format is only applicable for first time, when you change it, it is the new "default".