# How do I add a right click "Compress as ZIP" menu entry?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions

Step 1:
I wanted to add a menu as "Compress as ZIP" on right-click.
I know I can use a change default compress format as "ZIP" using gconf-editor.
But I wanted to add a new Menu Item for Compressing as ZIP without opening any other option dialog.

Step 2:
I wanted to Compress a file as ZIP and Rename it as an "epub".

Please let me know is it possible to zip&rename by adding a single menu item?
I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and Installed "Nautilus-Action-Configurations", but unsuccessful.

N.B. I have read this [Ask Ubuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6801/change-default-compress-option-in-nautilus-type-to-zip); I don't want to open a new window to choose me the format. It should be straight away saved as a ZIP.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom menu entries with the package `nautilus-actions`, see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86322/how-to-add-right-click-print-option-to-libreoffice-files-in-nautilus/90692#comment103677_90692) for a similar problem (there are nice screenshots too... :) ).

I couldn't manage to tell nautilus-actuions from which directory to run the path or to run two commands (i.e. `cd` to the correct directory first). Therefore 2 workarounds:

### Full paths

In nautilus-actions:
As command enter `zip` with the options `%d/%f.epub %M`.

This will include the whole path in the ZIP file. This is probably not suiteable for *.epub files. You can add the `-j` flag to include only files (no directories at all).

### Script

Place this script at `/usr/local/bin`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1
zip $2.epub $3
```

And use `your-script-name` as command and this options: `"%d" "%f.epub" "%m"`

I didn't test it, please report bugs (especially with spaces in the path or file names!) or edit this answer to confirm that it works!

Comment: I will test and will update