# gnome 3 right click compress option missing

Tags: gnome, nautilus, file-roller

I have what the title says.

I show [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6801/change-default-compress-option-in-nautilus-type-to-zip) answer but the file-roller has only folders "general" and "listing" and i didn't show an option to add right click compressing.

Answer (score 7):

I installed xarchiver ,i logged out and logged in and then it appeared.